# Filter tcpdump output (PCAP)

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

The following is the output from my PCAP file.

```
20:02:52.306161 192.162.70.150.58078 > 192.179.91.61.1194: P 635362993:635363048(55) ack 2046024708 win 4373 <nop,nop,timestamp 52993632 1059054949> (DF)
20:02:52.532863 192.179.91.61.1194 > 192.162.70.150.58078: . ack 55 win 32038 <nop,nop,timestamp 1059062357 52993632> (DF)
20:02:53.157004 802.1d unknown version
20:02:54.759542 arp who-has 192.168.70.34 tell 192.168.70.1
20:02:55.156980 802.1d unknown version
20:02:55.759507 arp who-has 192.168.70.6 tell 192.168.70.1
20:02:55.759540 arp who-has 192.168.70.105 tell 192.168.70.1
20:02:56.148167 192.179.91.61.1194 > 192.168.70.150.58078: P 1:56(55) ack 55 win 32038 <nop,nop,timestamp 1059065972 52993632> (DF)
20:02:56.148258 192.168.70.150.58078 > 192.179.91.61.1194: . ack 56 win 4373 <nop,nop,timestamp 52994592 1059065972> (DF)
```

Is there a way to filter out the contents in following pattern

```
Timestamp | source IP | source Port | destination IP | destination port | protocol | packet size
```

Available commands: `tcpdump`, `tcpslice`, `tcpstat`, `tcpprof`, `tcpparse`

Comment: Can you show the desired output for this example file content?

Comment: You should not post the same question on two SE sites. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64069#64069

Comment: And what should that give for the non-IP packets like the ARP/802.1d packets here. By "protocol", do you mean *transport* protocol on top of IP for those that are so (tcp/udp/sctp/icmp...)? By *packet size* do you mean the size of the frame as captured by tcpdump (including link layer and IP headers) or just the payload of those frames (so for IP packets, including the IP header and payload (including TCP/UDP header)) or the IP payload or the transport protocol payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To analyze the tcpdump from command line, `tcpparse` command can be used.
Eg:

```
# tcpparse tcpdump_file.pcap

6 192.135.33.41 132 > 192.168.20.119 1544 74
6 192.168.20.119 57604 > 192.135.33.41 1194 66
6 192.168.20.119 57604 > 192.135.33.41 1194 110
6 192.135.33.41 1194 > 192.168.20.119 57604 66
6 192.135.33.41 1194 > 192.168.20.119 57604 122
6 192.168.20.119 57604 > 192.135.33.41 1194 66
6 192.168.20.119 57604 > 192.135.33.41 1194 118
```

Columns explained :-

1. protocol
2. source IP address
3. source port
4. destination IP address
5. destination port
6. packet size.

Similarly `tcpdump -r` can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a better time loading your capture file into wireshark which will neatly do it for you in the "conversations" window.

Otherwise, have a look at this thread:
https://serverfault.com/questions/273066/tool-for-splitting-pcap-files-by-tcp-connection

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot install any other tools/commands, thats why I have listed down the available commands that can be used.

Comment: Can't you transfer the PCAP file to your computer for analysis with Wireshark ? If that's not an option either, then you could write a python script to parse the capture file (there are modules for that purpose), but you'll need Python to be installed on the machine.